# How I can include the angularJs application into an html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to include the angular application in a html page in the following way:

```
<html>
<script src="../../../common/lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
   $("#content").load("angular/index.html");

});
</script>
<div id ="content">        
</div>
</html>
```

When I try to open the page I can see the angular application but it doesn't work because I have an error about the ng-app (jquery.js:8152 Uncaught ReferenceError: angularApp ( the root element of the application) is not defined).

Somebody can help me?

Comment: What about an `iframe`: `<iframe src="angular/index.html"></iframe>`

Comment: I can't use the iframe.......:(!!!!

Comment: using jquery dom manipulations and angular at the same time is generally a bad idea. Few questions : Why can't you just initialize the angular app the standard way ? Where is `angular.js` loaded ? Could you use php or something serverside to include the angular template ?